# Read .DEX file as text using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, dex

I am currently working on a script that shall handle some generated .dex files (from another script). When i use the `fs.readFile(filename)` I get this as return in the terminal:

```
<Buffer 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 24 6e 61 6d 65 09 ... 3011 more bytes>
```

However if I open the file in VsCode or notepad it is perfectly readable text. Is there any way to parse this terminal response to original text, or is it a library for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use utf-8 encoding

with [readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) If no encoding is specified, then the raw buffer is returned.

```js
const fs = require("fs");

async function main(){
    const filePath = "./test.DEX";
    const encoding = "utf-8";
    
    const content = await fs.promises.readFile(filePath, encoding);

    console.log(content);
}

main();
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it